# I am looking for advanced resources on customizing MVC3 editor templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have been struggling with my customization of `EditorForModel` and the naming of HTML elements emitted by my code and the built-in MVC3 helpers. My code is very simple, and is clearly missing some subtleties, like naming the the rendered elements properly.

I am looking for advanced resources that can help me hone this area of my current development, especially with a view to subdividing a main view model across smaller sub-models, so that I can apply say three `EditorForModel` calls in one view, to split generated model editors across form columns or tab pages.

My current 'override' of the default `EditorForModel` template is as follows:

```
@{
    // TODO Filtering for subsets of model without having to bind separate models.
        var properties = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !pm.IsComplexType && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm));
    }
<fieldset>
    <legend>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName</legend>
    <ul class="form-column">
        @foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            <li>
                    @{
            if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml)
            {
                        @Html.Editor(prop.DisplayName ?? prop.PropertyName)
            }
            else
            {
                        @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName, (prop.IsRequired ? "* " : "") + (prop.DisplayName ?? prop.PropertyName))
                        @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
            }
                    }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

I have copied and modified this code from the Object.ascx example template on [this article](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) on [Brad Wilson's blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/). What resources can I consult to enrich this to cater for as many scenarios as possible, in as rich a manner as possible?

Comment: If you are looking for powerful html templates, I would recommend checking out the html template conventions from the FubuMVC team. They're 100% compatible with ASP.NET MVC and much more flexible/composable. I've been using them for 2+ years and absolutely love it. http://craigcav.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/applying-conventions-in-asp-net-mvc/ If you click through to Nick's post there's a link to how to make this work in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I don't think you can do too nuch better than that template, that is: a list of labels+Editor or Display for each property. If you want your object template to be very generic, the only improvement you can do is handling the Order attribute to decide in which order to list the properties. On the other side you can design your framework based on  custom attributes that control the way the template is organized. However, they way you do this depends strongly on your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template seems pretty good for a very generic editor. If I understand your question properly, you're looking for more ways to break up and filter your model properties.

One way to filter the model into subsets without having to create submodels would be to use attributes. You could create as many attributes as you want, and have them implement [IMetadataAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imetadataaware). There you could add arbitrary properties to the `ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues` property bag, and have your editor templates inspect those values.

Alternatively you could implement your own custom `ModelMetadataProvider` that returns a custom `ModelMetadata` object that had whatever properties you wanted.

Either would allow you to simply annotate your model to define filter behavior.

Both these methods are described by who else, Brad Wilson, in this [blog post.](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/why-you-dont-need-modelmetadataattributes.html)

Comment: Thanks @bhamlin, I have considered attributes for dividing my sub-models. This might even invoke the exciting prospect of developing a custom XML metadata provider so I could actually use a designer to manage metadata. Very article pointer, thanks.